# Use display flex to vertically align bootstrap btn on top of image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

As my title states I'm trying to vertically align my btn so it is center to my image. I'm not having any luck since my btn is sitting below my image and not on top. I've tried a lot but nothing seems to work. I've posted my HTML and CSS so maybe someone can guide me where to start.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="imgAbout">
          <img src="img/team/neil580x410.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Neil Elmouchi Bio">
          <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="bios/teamBioNeil.html" role="button">View More</a>
        </div>
      <h1>Neil Elmouchi</h1>
      <h3>Chairman &amp; CEO<br> 
      Senior Wealth Advisor</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#about img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.imgAbout {
  background: #d5d5d5;
  text-align: center;
}

.imgAbout img {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.imgAbout img:hover {
   opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Comment: are you looking for something like this - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NAXQRG?editors=1111

Comment: Well I would like the btn to be vertically center on top of the img

Comment: check this updated codepen -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/groVwV?editors=1111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were confused because you forgot element usually can't **overlap** each other. So in order to have a button **on the top** of a larger image, we usually use overlay (position: absolute) technique for more flexibility on image dimension. Here is your modified example

```
.imgAbout {
  position: relative;
}

/* overlay to inherit dimension from imgAbout and centralize button */

.center-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.imgAbout img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.imgAbout:hover img {
   opacity: 0.4;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0bt4q9vk/

Comment: Thank you this is the exact solution I was looking for.

Comment: i am glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your expected result , use below option

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="imgAbout">
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Neil Elmouchi Bio">
      <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="bios/teamBioNeil.html" role="button">View More</a>
    </div>
    <h1>Neil Elmouchi</h1>
    <h3>Chairman &amp; CEO<br> 
      Senior Wealth Advisor</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#about img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a{
vertical-align:top;
display:block;
margin-top:-430px
}

.imgAbout {
  background: #d5d5d5;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top:20px;
 }

.imgAbout img {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}



.imgAbout img:hover {
   opacity: 0.4;
}
h1,h3{
  position:relative;
  top:400px;
}
```

Codepen-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/mEpNOY?editors=1111